# Exception handling in android

Tags: android, exception, android-toast

I need to show the exception as a toast message in my app,but the following code not working,How can I modify this?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            if (btn66 == v) {
                ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
                value.put(DBhelper.Amount, txtBudget.getText().toString());
                value.put(DBhelper.Description, txr.getText().toString());

                if (txtBudget.length() == 0) {
                    txtBudget.requestFocus();
                    txtBudget.setError("Field Cannot Be Empty");
                } else {

                    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                    db.insert(DBhelper.TABLE2, null, value);
                    db.close();
                    clearfield();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Budget add Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    fetchData2();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception sce)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error duplicate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(sce.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

> 10-14 23:41:21.637  14498-14498/com.example.username.weddingplanning
>   E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting name=d
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column name is not unique (code 19)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native
>   Method)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:968)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1575)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1445)
>               at com.example.username.weddingplanning.addcategory.onClick(addcategory.java:67)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18398)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: Show the result you get

Comment: I didn't get any error message in toast,but in logcat the exception error details are coming.

Comment: add logcat with your question

Comment: check my updated question plz

Answer (score 3):

You can see from the Toast documentation for the constructor you're using:

```
public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)

Parameters
    context     The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.
    text        The text to show. Can be formatted text.
    duration    How long to display the message. Either LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG
```

that the first parameter is a `Context`.

You're passing in `this` EDIT: which might not be the correct `Context` from which a `Toast` can be constructed.

You need to pass it the `Context` of the `Activity` or `Application` for it to work properly.

Comment: I tried like that too,still it's not giving exception toast message.

Comment: It will show the "Budget add Successfully" message on success but not the "Error duplicate" message on exception?

Comment: yes,if I add the duplicate value also,It's showing success message  "Budget add Successfully".(even though it's showing success message,duplicate values does not get added to database)

Comment: You tried both YourActivity.this and YourActivity.this.getApplicationContext()?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `YourActivity.this` in First Argument of Toast.

Example:

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I tried like that too,still it's not giving exception toast message,It's  giving success message as "Successfully added".but It's not getting added to the database.

Comment: I think catch block will not show Toast Message so you have to keep `true` or `false` and after catch block you can display Toast as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to check for result code of insert  statement.
insert statement always returns  the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred.

Comment: So `int result = db.insert(DBhelper.TABLE2, null, value);` then?

Comment: if (result == -1)  { show  error } else  { do your work}